# Censoring the Zen tradition

Tags: discussion, chat

I'm a bit dumbfounded as to why the mods deleted my comments in this chat.  Koans are part of the Rinzai canon.  Deleting them is favoring one sect over another.

https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/117255/discussion-between-the-tech-expert-guy-and-user20010

Comment: @terdon resolved this.  Still, I think it points to an identifiable problem - mods from other stacks shouldn't be able to block content on sites they know nothing about.

Answer (score 0):

I flagged it as offensive since it talked about ending the life of the Buddha and some other offensive stuff. I'm a Buddhist and that's why I flagged them as offensive. So it's not censoring. However, I'd love to have @ruben2020's opinion.